# Powershell AuthorisationManager check failed

Tags: powershell, authorizationmanager

This is just a blank script. I have made the ExecutionPolicy unrestricted as this is just a developer machine. Is there anything I'm missing? I'm running this on a win 2003 server virtualised.

cheers

[alt text http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/4745/68808602.jpg](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/4745/68808602.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is not due to execution policy, it looks like whatever is on line 34 has failed.

The error you get for execution policy violation talks about execution policy.

Comment: Oh silly me, You get this error if you have nothing in the file for powershell to execute